# save variables in local storage and then compare

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Due to the site I am working on I need to first store some variables and then compare them.

I can't get my fiddle to work if my values are indeed equal. I have never used local storage before so not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/QuLub/2/

I have just added in the values in the divs so that it is easy to see what they are and won't be in the code.

```
    var userID = user(2, 7),
        playerID = player(14),
        savedUserid,
        savedUPlayerid;


    function user(a, b) {
        return a  *  b              
    }

    function player(a) {
        return a              
    }

    function saveData(x) {
        localStorage.setItem('userID', x);
    }

    function saveData(x) {
        localStorage.setItem('playerID', x);
    }


    savedUserid = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('userID'));
    savedPlayerid = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('playerID'));
    if (typeof savedUserid === typeof savedPlayerid) {
        alert (true)
    }
    else {
        alert (false)
    }
```

Comment: Why are you comparing the **type** of the values? `parseInt` *always* returns a number. But besides, you haven't actually explained what the problem is. What is the input? What is the output? What is the output you expect? You have a typo in `savedPlayrerid = ...`.

Comment: You declare `savedUPlayerid` but you use `savedPlayerid`

Comment: hah. he also misspelled it a second time, in a different way. `savedPlayrerid`

Comment: doh, updated fiddle but this still hasn't fixed my issue,
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/QuLub/2/

Comment: Lol indeed. Well you have nice tools in JSFiddle called TidyUp and JSHint. This is what you have after fixing a bit your code : http://jsfiddle.net/QuLub/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few problems... you werent saving the values, and you were comparing typeof instead of the actual values (as someone else pointed out). Anyway, this is working:

http://jsfiddle.net/QuLub/7/

```
var userID = user(2, 7),
    playerID = player(14),
    savedUserid,
    savedUPlayerid;


function user(a, b) {
    return a  *  b              
}

function player(a) {
    return a              
}

function saveData(type, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(type, value);
}

saveData('userID', userID);
saveData('playerID', playerID);

console.log(localStorage.getItem('userID'));
savedUserid = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('userID'));
savedUPlayerid = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('playerID'));
if (savedUserid === savedUPlayerid) {
    alert (true)
}
else {
    alert (false)
}



document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = savedUserid;
document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = savedUPlayerid;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and main problem I notice is that you never call the `saveData` function. Also, as you can see, you have 2 functions with the same name, so they will just replace one another.

```
function saveData(x) {
    localStorage.setItem('userID', x);
}

function saveData(x) {
    localStorage.setItem('playerID', x);
}
```

Because of this,

```
localStorage.getItem('userID')
```

and

```
localStorage.getItem('playerID')
```

are both null.

The second mistake is that you misspelled: `savedPlayerid` as `savedPlayrerid`.

Working jsFiddle with the modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/QuLub/3/

Comment: thanks but if you change the value of Player so they are not equal it still returns true
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/QuLub/8/

Comment: Because you are comparing `typeof`. Number === Number. Didn't you know ?